# Why are currency exchange rates so different in Egypt?

Tags: money, exchange, egypt

I’m in Alexandria. Google shows the exchange rate of EUR to EGP at 1 to 33. I get the same rate when I use my credit card. But when I exchange euros at different places in the streets, in the shops I get much more favourable trades (1 to 40, even 1 to 49).

I read that EGP isn’t pegged to USD anymore, which would trigger independent black market prices. So what’s the deal then?

Comment: Is this at chain forex places, or just money changers on the street?

Comment: I was buying a suit in a random street shop. The guy exchanged euros for 1-to-40 in a neighboring shop. My friend exchanged for 1-49 in a jewelry shop.

Comment: That's fairly normal in countries with "weak" currency. In Argentina you can get the "blue rate" on the streets which is about twice as good as the official rate. Even hotels give you a 25% discount for paying with a credit card (at the official rate) instead of cash. In Argentina it's perfectly legal, I don't know about Egypt.

Comment: "The guy exchanged euros for 1-to-40 in a neighboring shop": was it a currency exchange or some other sort of shop exchanging the euros as a convenience?

Comment: @phoog It wasn’t a currency exchange shop, was just a street money dealer probably

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without getting into Egypt's current [economic crisis](https://www.aljazeera.com/economy/2023/10/6/egypts-bonds-spiral-lower-after-moodys-downgrade-over-economic-woes), suffice it to say the country has a number of capital controls that aim to limit outflows of Egyptian currency. In October, the government [instructed local banks to restrict](https://www.reuters.com/markets/currencies/egypt-restricts-foreign-currency-credit-card-use-2023-10-17/) the use of Egyptian Pound debit and credit cards outside the country and [imposed limits](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/egyptian-banks-tighten-dollar-limits-after-currency-pressure-mounts-2022-10-10/) on the amount of foreign currency Egyptian bank accountholders can withdraw. Foreign currency for imports is apparently subject to prioritization for "essential" goods.

As a result, the "official" exchange rate doesn't represent the true price people are willing to pay for Euros. If people could get all the Euros they wanted from their local bank at something like 1 to 33 (and if their local bank could get all the Euros it wanted from the central bank), they'd gladly do so, but they can't because of the capital controls. So people who still want more foreign currency are willing/forced to pay a higher price for it because the supply is limited. You, since the Euros in your wallet you flew in with aren't subject to the same restrictions, are offering some of that supply and so benefit from the higher price.

I can't speak to the legality of these parallel market exchange transactions in Egypt.